# How to deploy and start a console application with scheduled tasks on Windows?

Tags: c#, deployment, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a C# console application that I want to be able to deploy to a remote Windows Server 2012. I also want the application to execute on certain intervals e.g. last day of each month. I guess Windows Scheduled Tasks is the preferred way to do this.

I would love it if I could configure the scheduling, package it up with the application and deploy it to the target server in just one click (preferably from Visual Studio).
Is this even remotely possible and if so, how?

Comment: Wix installer can do this : http://kamivaniea.com/?p=632

Answer (score 3):

You can use Task scheduler for this purpose.

[Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx)

There's a nuget package that built around it.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/
Find detailed documentation here
https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
  {
     // Create a new task definition and assign properties
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

     // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
     td.Triggers.Add(new MonthlyTrigger { RunOnLastDayOfMonth = true });

     // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("your.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

     // Register the task in the root folder
     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

  }
```

Comment: Yes. This however doesn't take deployment into account.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old, but here is a concept you can follow. Like I said, this is a concept as I can't validate all the way through because how locked down my job has our work stations; I end up with a "Access is Denied" error.

In your program, add the `using {}` block that @Vishnu Prasad mentioned above:

```
if(args != null && args.Contains("-CreateSchedule"))
{
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {
        // Get the company name 
        FileVersionInfo versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string companyName = versionInfo.CompanyName;

        // Set the program path
        string folderPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles.ToString(), companyName);
        string programPath = string.Format(@"{0}\program.exe", folderPath);

        // Create a new task definition and assign properties
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "The program does what it does";

        // Set trigger and action and other properties...
        td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;

        // Create a trigger that will fire at the end of the month, every month
        td.Triggers.Add(new MonthlyTrigger { RunOnLastDayOfMonth = true });

        // Create an action that will launch the program whenever the trigger fires
        td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(programPath, "'arg a' 'arg b' 'etc'", null));

        ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("TheTaskName", td);
    }

    // Don't let the program perform any other functions that aren't needed
    Exit();
}
```

The process below was used with Visual Studio 2012.

1. First, add a new Windows Setup project to your solution; you may need to search for it and install the template. This installer project will allow you to deploy your project as a msi build for later installation.
2. Once the installer project is created, add the project output to the Application Folder, along with anything else you'll need.
3. Build and deploy to the host.

I would recommend installing from the commandline so you can output the results to a log file, such as:

`msiexec /package "c:\path\to\file.msi" /quiet ALLUSERS=1 /log "install.log"`

After you install the msi file, run it for the first time with the `-CreateSchedule` parameter
`program.exe -CreateSchedule`

You can also create a batch file to automate the above commandline tasks.